# Any easy way to create a DataFrame of rows that contains inconstant number of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Now I have two series, sharing the same index but containing different number of values separated in comma

For example,

Series 1

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "A,B" |
| 1 | "C,D,E" |
| 2 | "F,G,H,I,J,K" |

Series 2

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "apple, banana" |
| 1 | "citrus, donut, egg" |
| 2 | "fries, grape, ham, ice, jackfruit, kale" |

What is the easiest way to create the table below:

| index | Letter 1 | Food 1 | Letter 2 | Food 2 | Letter 3 | Food 3 | Letter 4 | Food 4 | Letter 5 | Food 5 | Letter 6 | Food 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "A" | "apple" | "B" | "banana" |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | "C" | "citrus" | "D" | "donut" | "E" | "egg" |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | "F" | "fries" | "G" | "grape" | "H" | "ham" | "I" | "ice" | "J" | "jackfruit" | "K" | "kale" |

Would be good with some sample codes.

Do I have to iterate all rows and append a number of commas accordingly, and then iterate again to split the values? It sounds quite memory-intensive if so.

Comment: You seem to be asking 2 different questions at the same time "easiest" and "least memory intensive". There is no reason to expect both at the same time, so what do you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to iterate all rows and append a number of commas accordingly, and then iterate again to split the values?

In pandas best avoid looping, if exist vectorized methods like here.

---

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for both Series/columns, then join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), for correct order use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df1['value'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna('')
df2 = df2['value'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna('')
#if there is comma with space
#df2 = df2['value'].str.split(',\s+', expand=True).fillna('')

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('Letter','Food'))
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1] + 1}')
print (df)
  Letter 1  Food 1 Letter 2  Food 2 Letter 3 Food 3 Letter 4 Food 4 Letter 5  \
0        A   apple        B  banana                                            
1        C  citrus        D   donut        E    egg                            
2        F   fries        G   grape        H    ham        I    ice        J   

      Food 5 Letter 6 Food 6  
0                             
1                             
2  jackfruit        K   kale
```

Comment: Elegant! Appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**First**(line 1~9) : setting 3 empty data_frame for concating it each matched data later.

Also setting lst_1 and lst_2 each is list of letters and fruits.

```
import pandas as pd

lst_1 = ["A,B","C,D,E","F,G,H,I,J,K"]
lst_2 = ["apple,banana", "citrus,donut,egg",
         "fries,grape,ham, ice,jackfruit,kale",]

Data_Frame_0 = pd.DataFrame({})
Data_Frame_1 = pd.DataFrame({})
Data_Frame_2 = pd.DataFrame({})
```

**Second:** using for-loop and zip function allocates the letter_value and fruit_value(name).

For making number behind of each columns, allocates number of range(len(letter_values)) too.

```
for letter_value, fruit_value in zip(lst_1,lst_2):
    letter_values = letter_value.split(",")
    fruit_values = fruit_value.split(",")
    for each_letter_value, each_fruit_values, column_name_number in zip(letter_values,fruit_values, range(len(letter_values))):
        Loop_Data_Frame = pd.DataFrame({f'Letter{column_name_number+1}':[each_letter_value],
                                   f'Food{column_name_number+1}':[each_fruit_values]})
```

Len(letter_values) is same with last number of Data_Frames columns number.
i.e) when letter_value is "A,B" letter_values is list consisting of "A","B"
Since we will make different columns following the each letter or fruit.

the number elements of each list is same with columns last number.
"A" will be Letter 1 columns data, "B" will be Letter 2 columns data in Data_Frame.

So using range() allocate the len(letter_values) by using for-loop into the last of the column so automatically setting the columns name.

**Third:** concating each Data frame and reindex of Data_Frame

```
        if letter_value == lst_1[0]:
            Data_Frame_0 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_0,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)
        elif letter_value == lst_1[1]:
            Data_Frame_1 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_1,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)
        elif letter_value == lst_1[2]:
            Data_Frame_2 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_2,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)

Data_Frame = pd.concat([Data_Frame_0,Data_Frame_1,Data_Frame_2])
Data_Frame.index = [0,1,2]

print(Data_Frame)
```

**Outcome** will be

```
  Letter1   Food1 Letter2   Food2  ... Letter5      Food5 Letter6 Food6
0       A   apple       B  banana  ...     NaN        NaN     NaN   NaN
1       C  citrus       D   donut  ...     NaN        NaN     NaN   NaN
2       F   fries       G   grape  ...       J  jackfruit       K  kale
```

Give me comment if you can't understand about my code! Have a nice day

The whole code without description ↓

```
import pandas as pd

lst_1 = ["A,B","C,D,E","F,G,H,I,J,K"]
lst_2 = ["apple,banana", "citrus,donut,egg",
         "fries,grape,ham, ice,jackfruit,kale",]

Data_Frame_0 = pd.DataFrame({})
Data_Frame_1 = pd.DataFrame({})
Data_Frame_2 = pd.DataFrame({})

for letter_value, fruit_value in zip(lst_1,lst_2):
    letter_values = letter_value.split(",")
    fruit_values = fruit_value.split(",")
    for each_letter_value, each_fruit_values, column_name_number in zip(letter_values,fruit_values, range(len(letter_values))):
        Loop_Data_Frame = pd.DataFrame({f'Letter{column_name_number+1}':[each_letter_value],
                                   f'Food{column_name_number+1}':[each_fruit_values]})

        if letter_value == lst_1[0]:
            Data_Frame_0 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_0,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)
        elif letter_value == lst_1[1]:
            Data_Frame_1 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_1,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)
        elif letter_value == lst_1[2]:
            Data_Frame_2 = pd.concat([Data_Frame_2,Loop_Data_Frame], axis=1)

Data_Frame = pd.concat([Data_Frame_0,Data_Frame_1,Data_Frame_2])
Data_Frame.index = [0,1,2]

print(Data_Frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think we can use only Series 2 without Series 1, because each values of Series 1 are from first letter of values in Series 2. so i made example dataset only Series 2(the name of it in my code : series, and type of it is dataframe, *NOT series*)

```
# 00. module

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 0. make a dataset

l={'value':["apple, banana", "citrus, donut, egg","fries, grape, ham, ice, jackfruit, kale"]}
series=pd.DataFrame(l)
print(series) #type of series is dataframe NOT series!

# 1-1. reshape long(in python: melt)

series=series.value.str.split(pat=',', expand=True)
series['id']=list(range(1,series.shape[0]+1))
print(series)
var=list(series.columns)
var.remove('id')
melt=pd.melt(series,id_vars='id',value_vars=var,value_name='Food')
print(melt)

# 1-2. make Letter without series1

melt['Letter']=melt.Food.str.strip().str.get(0).str.upper()
print(melt)

# 1-3. reshape wide(in python: pivot)

df=pd.pivot(melt,index='id',columns='variable' ,values=['Food','Letter']).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1] + 1}')
print(df)

# 1-4. order columns

collist=[]
for i in range(1,6+1):

    rx=str(i)+'$'
    collist=collist+list(df.filter(regex=rx).columns)

df=df[collist]
print(df)
```